# Android DataBinding not wroking after adding proguard

Tags: java, android, data-binding, proguard, android-proguard

i am facing an issue with android data binding and proguard rule,

Enable android data binding from gradle file

```
 dataBinding {
            enabled = true
        }
```

Databinding is  working fine before adding proguard in gradle file 
when the  **minifyEnabled** set false app working fine

```
debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
```

and if I change the **minifyEnabled** to true the app crash on binding view.

```
debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
```

and show error

```
W/ActivityManager: Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@426364e8

04-12 18:30:57.666 15455-15455/com.theskillsrainbow D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
04-12 18:30:57.666 15455-15455/com.theskillsrainbow W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4170bba8)
04-12 18:30:57.666 15455-15455/com.theskillsrainbow W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-12 18:30:57.666 15455-15455/com.theskillsrainbow W/System.err:     at com.theskillsrainbow.f.s$1.a(Unknown Source)
04-12 18:30:57.666 15455-15455/com.theskillsrainbow W/System.err:     at d.g$a$1$1.run(Unknown Source)
04-12 18:30:57.666 15455-15455/com.theskillsrainbow W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
04-12 18:30:57.667 15455-15455/com.theskillsrainbow W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-12 18:30:57.667 15455-15455/com.theskillsrainbow W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-12 18:30:57.667 15455-15455/com.theskillsrainbow W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5028)
04-12 18:30:57.667 15455-15455/com.theskillsrainbow W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-12 18:30:57.667 15455-15455/com.theskillsrainbow W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-12 18:30:57.667 15455-15455/com.theskillsrainbow W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:788)
04-12 18:30:57.667 15455-15455/com.theskillsrainbow W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:604)
04-12 18:30:57.667 15455-15455/com.theskillsrainbow W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Proguard Rule for data binding that I used

```
#databinding
-dontwarn android.databinding.**
-keep class android.databinding.** { *; }
-keep class android.databinding.annotationprocessor.** { *; }
```